# How do I control the element name when serializing child classes?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

If I have something like:

```
public abstract class Animal { }

[XmlRoot]
public class Dog:Animal { }

[XmlRoot]
Public class Cat:Animal { }
```

How do I go about serializing (and then be able to de-serialize) a Cat object like:

```
<Cat> </Cat>
```

and not something like:

```
<Animal type="Cat"> </Animal>
```

I've tried using different combinations from the System.Xml.Serialization and System.Runtime.Serialization namespaces, but I can't seem to get it.

I can get a serialized object to look the way I want by specifying the type of the object in the serializer.  This works for serialization, but not for de-serialization..because I don't know the type of object in the xml.

---

One possible solution would be:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{ 
    static Dictionary<String,Type> typeDic;
    static Animal()
    {
        typeDic = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        //Get classes in the same namespace of this object
        Type ctype = typeof(Animal);
        Type[] types = ctype.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, ctype.Namespace, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();

        //For any XmlRootAttribute objects, add the ElementName and Type to a dictionary
        foreach(Type type in types)
        {
            foreach (XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlRootAttribute), false))
            {
                typeDic.Add(xmlRoot.ElementName, type);
            }
        }
    }
    public static Content read(String XML)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = null;

        //check the first element to see what the name is, then create the serializer using the type from the dictionary
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(GenerateStreamFromString(XML));
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.Name == "xml")
        {
            while (reader.MoveToContent() != XmlNodeType.Element) { }
        }
        if (typeDic.ContainsKey(reader.Name))
            s = new XmlSerializer(typeDic[reader.Name]);
        else
            throw new Exception("Unknown Type in read");
        return (Content)s.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    public static string write<T>(T f)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        s.Serialize(stream, f);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return StreamToString(stream);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Dog")]
public class Dog:Animal { }

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Cat")]
Public class Cat:Animal { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for a long time and could not figure it out either. the only thing i could come up with is using some reflection and generating the doc myself:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>
        {
            new Dog{Name = "Ernie", HasFleas = true},
            new Cat{ Name = "Bert", Collar = "Blue with a little bell" }
        };

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","true");
        doc.Add(new XElement("root", animals.Select(animal => animal.GetElement)));

        Console.WriteLine(doc);


    }
}


public abstract class Animal 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public XElement GetElement 
    {
        get 
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();
            XElement result = new XElement(type.Name);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in
                type.GetProperties().Where(pi=> pi.CustomAttributes.Any(ca=> ca.AttributeType == typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute))))
            {
                result.Add(new XAttribute(property.Name,property.GetValue(this)));
            }
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in
                type.GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute))))
            {
                result.Add(new XElement(property.Name,property.GetValue(this)));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}

public class Dog : Animal 
{ 
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool HasFleas { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal 
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Collar { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize you have to do the other way round so some form of factory.